# Finding the angles of a triangle using algebraic expressions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I think I have solved this question but want to check if I am correct with my formula

I used the theorem (rule) : the measure of the exterior angle of a triangle is equal to the sum of the remote (opposite) interior angles.

My workings as follows:

I am given one interior angle as $25^{\circ}$.

Another interior as $x + 15^{\circ}$ and the other is missing.

The final angle given is an exterior angle $3x - 10^{\circ}$ that is opposite the two interior angles.

$x+ 15^{\circ} + 25^{\circ}$ (opposite interior angles) $= 3x - 10^{\circ}$ (exterior angle).
\begin{align*}
x + 15^{\circ} + 25^{\circ} & = 3x - 10^{\circ}\\
x - x + 15^{\circ} + 25^{\circ} + 10^{\circ} & = 3x - 10^{\circ} + 10^{\circ} - x\\
50^{\circ} & = 2x\\
\frac{50^{\circ}}{2} & = \frac{2x}{2}\\
25^{\circ} & = x\\
x & = 25^{\circ}
\end{align*}

So one of the interior angles is a
Ready given in this question which is: $25$ degrees

And the other given is: $x + 15^{\circ}$.
So if $x=25^{\circ}$ then this angle $= 40$ degrees.

And the exterior angle is 
$3 \times 25 - 10 = 65$ degrees.

Am I correct in this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We wish to see your picture, Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to attach an image, only a link so I've added a description instead that describes where each angle is:                                             "I am given one interior angle as 25 Another interior as x + 15 And the other is missing The final angle given is an exterior angle 3x - 10 that is opposite the two interior angles"

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.
$$x+15^{\circ}+25^{\circ}=3x-10^{\circ}$$ or
$$x=25^{\circ},$$
which gives measured angles of the triangle: $25^{\circ}$, $40^{\circ}$ and $115^{\circ}$.